# can't upload audio file to server using PHP script from IOS device

Tags: php, ios, audio, file-upload

i have this **PHP** script to upload an image or audio file into a server

```
<?php
include "config.php";

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
 {
   if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
   switch($imagetype)
   {
       case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
       case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
       case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
       case 'image/png': return '.png';
       case 'audio/mp3' : return '.mp3';
       case 'audio/mp4' : return '.mp4';
       case 'audio/wav' : return '.wav';
       default: return false;
   }
}

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) 
{
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    if($ext!=false)
    {
            $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
            $target_path = "img/personal/".$imagename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path))
        {
            $query_upload="INSERT INTO `images_tbl` (`image_id` ,`image_path` ,`subission_date`)
            VALUES (NULL ,  '".$target_path."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
            mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error()); 
            header("location:room.php");
        }
        else
            {
               exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
            }
    }

}
header("location:room.php");
?>
```

it works good when uploading a file from windows OS but when uploading  from IOS (an iphone 6 mobile phone  device ) when uploading image it works but it does not let user to upload audio file and when user want to upload a file it just gives these options : image below 
[image]

when user hits **choose file ** from file upload form it gives those options to upload just and then can't upload an audio .
how can i fix it .
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to figure out your question, I BELEIVE it is because of the AAC Protected, Apple Lossless, and Audible files, try different audio files since there are quite a few. And only a few are supported.

Heres a list of supported:

- MP3
- MP4
- WAV

Hope it helped!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: i'm using those audio formats but does not let me still to upload an audio file